# video only play when it is in active window?

Tags: jquery, flash, video, html5-video

i have a webpage in which a video is embedded between content (upper & lower). when video is display on active window its only play rather than it pause while scrolling.

i have been asked this problem in stackoverflow chat and they give me two function but its not working in it

```
onpageshow()
onpagehide()
```

for example

> http://demo.teads.tv/inread/147/514

it describes whole what i want.

Is there is any solution for it.i need a direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long efforts, i found a pretty much example for this problem.....

and the link is :

> http://jsbin.com/ocupor/1/edit

thanks a lot whose create this.